# what is maximum size of image we can use with ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing

I am setting image to Label and before that I am creating ImageIcon Object
`ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(PathToImage,"Image");
  jLabel.setIcon(icon);`
when image size exceeding 4 MB i am getting "**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**"

Is this error related to image size or something else?

If it is by large image size then any possible workaround ?

Comment: How much memory is your computer running?

Comment: @klonq :: My PC has 750 MB of RAM.

Comment: Note that '4 MB' tells us nothing about the width x height, transparency or bit depth of the image.  That information is more relevant than the byte size on disk.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson :: so you mean to say I should look for image quality rather than size on disk ... right ?  and for image is there any way to get value of width , height ,transparency or bit depth ?

Comment: "I should look for image quality rather than size on disk ... right ?"  Think of it this way.  A JPEG can have a compression level (as can several other image types).  A 400x300 image of the exact same picture can be saved at differing levels of compression for different final file sizes.  High compression, that size can be very small - but by the time Java loads them, same size.  BTW - Some of those things are easy (once the image is loaded), but I do not see the immediate relevance of getting those details 'in Java'.  I meant to open it in your favorite image editor to get the info.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding these JVM parameters at run time:

java -Xms256m -Xmx512m

That will increase the available memory to your program.

Comment: : Thanks for your comment ..  how to set JVM parameters at run-time ?

Comment: just add those -X commands to the command line.  If you're running in Eclipse you set them up as JVM arguments in the "Run As.." dialog.  Otherwise just preface them before your main classname when you run the "java" command.